# Как зафиксировать форму на рабочем столе поверх любых открывающихся окон, форм...?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть чужая сторонняя программа - обычная Drop Zone. Тянешь на ее документы, а она их архивирует. Дело в том, что я запускаю свою программы и разворачиваю на весь экран и вот эта сторонняя форма тускло отображается на моей форме. При наведении курсора эффект тусклости исчезает и она становится активной, непрозрачной.Чтобы я не делал сторонняя форма всегда находится поверх любых открытых окон или программ. Как повторить тоже самое?

Comment: Свойство [TopMost](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.topmost?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Form_TopMost) выставить?

Comment: Спасибо, огромное. не знал этого

Comment: пожалуйста, удачи с задачей